# AOSP keyboard and unicode characters

Tags: keyboard, 5.1-lollipop

Is it possible that unicode characters like š,č,ž are shown next to standard characters on the keyboard? My keyboard is Slovenian (QWERTZ), and I have to long press 's' to get the 'š' character. My system is Android 5.1.1 (CyanogenMod 12.1).